# Как с помощью обычного js ajax передать значение поля в PHP файл?

Tags: javascript, ajax

HTML

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" id="field" name="field" value=""/>
</form>
```

Как с помощью обычного js ajax передать значение поля в пхп файл, и по условию допустим через алерт вывести или "ок" или "не ок" , и если условие верное , тогда отправить форму, если же нет, то не отправляем

php

```
if ($_POST['field'] == "1"){echo "go";} else {echo "err";}
```

пробую так

```
var field = document.getElementById('field').value;
```

и в самом ajax запросе через метод `send` передать значение поля `.send ("field")` а пхп файл явно не видит `$_POST['field'];`

Comment: Что вы сделали для решения своей проблемы? С какими трудностями столкнулись? Гугл молчит как партизан?

Comment: пробую так 
`var field = document.getElementById('field').value;`
и в самом ajax запросе через метод `send` передать значение поля `.send ("field")`
а пхп файл явно не видит `$_POST['field'];`
в гугле кроме jquery ничего не могу найти

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```
var xmlhttp,
    field = document.getElementById('field').value,
    params = 'field=' + field;

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        } else {
            alert('Что-то пошло не так')
        }
    }
}

xmlhttp.open('POST', 'my_ajax.php', true);
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

и гуглить `XMLHttpRequest`

**Update:**

```
document.getElementById('id_вашей_формы').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    var field = document.getElementById('field').value;
    if (field != 'нужное значение') {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } else {
        //ваш POST-запрос и остальные необходимые действия
    }
});
```

Comment: спасибо , помогло, но как сделать что бы форма не отправлялась пока не будет нужного значение

Comment: @ddeadlink обрабатывать событие отправки формы и проверять заполненность полей

Comment: я имею в виду, если в результате проверки поле будет не того значения, то в таком случае без доп. инструкций форма всё равно отправится

Comment: используйте `preventDefault()` чтобы не отправилась. Обновила ответ